# Using datepart in query with group by

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I'm trying to get a select query that is the following format using `Datepart` and `SUM`

Please see the [Link to SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f2ef2/4) which has this all set up.

I am trying to use `Datepart` within the `Group by` but it keeps giving an error.

```
| Material | TaskList | Weeknum | Sum of Signoff Qty |
------------------------------------------------------
|  xx      |    aa    |   11    |     8              |
|  xx      |    bb    |   11    |     7              |
|  xx      |    aa    |   12    |     8              |
|  xx      |    bb    |   12    |     7              |
|  yy      |    aa    |   11    |     22             |
|  yy      |    bb    |   11    |     20             |
|  yy      |    aa    |   12    |     22             |
|  yy      |    bb    |   12    |     20             |
```

Generating test data:

```
CREATE TABLE tangoTable 
    (
     [Task List] varchar(50), 
     [DateandTime] varchar(50), 
     [SignoffQty] varchar(30),
     [Material] varchar(50)
    );

INSERT INTO tangoTable
([Task List]
 , [DateandTime]
 , [SignoffQty]
 , [Material])
VALUES
('aa', '3/14/16 21:41', '4', 'xx'),
('aa', '3/16/16 11:41', '4', 'xx'),
('bb', '3/18/16 20:00', '3', 'xx'),
('bb', '3/19/16 10:00', '4', 'xx'),
('aa', '3/14/16 10:00', '10', 'yy'),
('aa', '3/16/16 10:00', '12', 'yy'),
('bb', '3/18/16 11:41', '9', 'yy'),
('bb', '3/19/16 11:41', '11', 'yy'),
('aa', '3/07/16 21:41', '4', 'xx'),
('aa', '3/07/16 11:41', '4', 'xx'),
('bb', '3/07/16 20:00', '3', 'xx'),
('bb', '3/07/16 10:00', '4', 'xx'),
('aa', '3/07/16 10:00', '10', 'yy'),
('aa', '3/07/16 10:00', '12', 'yy'),
('bb', '3/07/16 11:41', '9', 'yy'),
('bb', '3/07/16 11:41', '11', 'yy')
;
```

Query Attempt:

```
Select 
[Material]
,[Task List]
,Datepart(wk, [DateandTime]) as WeekNum
,Sum(Cast(SignoffQty as Int)) as 'Sum of Signoff'
from tangoTable
Group By
[Material], [Task List], WeekNum
```

Comment: Thank you Consider Me - I should have added that. Also I'm not sure why the query attempt doesn't show. Maybe the URL is wrong. I also added the query attempt to the question.

Comment: When using SQL Fiddle you need to press Build schema button, then press Run SQL button and __after__ those actions copy the page link. It will change. You probably copied your link without running your SQL statement. I've edited your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `date_part(wk, dateandtime)` to get week number of a year.

You need to cast your `signoffqty` value to `int` datatype to be able to `sum` it up.

```
SELECT
  material, 
  [Task List], 
  datepart(wk, dateandtime) AS weeknum, 
  sum(cast(signoffqty as int)) as sum_of_signoff_qty
FROM
  tangotable
GROUP BY
  material, [Task List], datepart(wk, dateandtime)
```

---

I don't think `varchar(30)` for `[SignoffQty]` column is a good fit. It should rather be some numeric datatype.

If you happen to have a non-numeric character there your query will return an **error**:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'value_here' to data type
>   int.

---

As *@Used_By_Already* correctly stated:

Starting with **SQL Server 2012** you could use [`TRY_CAST()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx) function instead of `CAST()`  which:

> Returns a value cast to the specified data type if the cast succeeds;
>   otherwise, returns null.

Beware that the behaviour would change. For a given `material, [Task list], weeknum` pair with values in `signoffqty` column like:

```
5
3x -- varchar!
8
```

the sum would return: `13` instead of conversion type error.

Comment: Wow - such a simple answer - I was so close. Thank you VERY much!

Comment: And thanks for the note about `Cast` - I wish I could change the table schema however it's locked down, the only thing I really can do is select query it. Thanks again!

Comment: Sometimes we're stuck what we're stuck with. This implies bad design though and may break your query on non numeric values, just a heads up! Good luck.

Comment: If you have a recent version of SQL Server use `TRY_CAST()` instead of cast https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx if that column contains data that cannot be converted it will halt the query with an error, using TRY_CAST() would avoid the error but not resolve the bad data.

Comment: @Used_By_Already Good addition, thanks. I didn't know about try_cast function :-)